# Does select-keys preserve order from its keyseq?

Tags: collections, clojure

Looking at the example:
`(into [] (select-keys {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} [:c :b])) => [[:c 3] [:b 2]]`
Is it guaranteed that returned result will preserve order declared in second parameter of `select-key`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`select-keys` returns a map which are unorderd, so you can't rely on it. Small maps are represented as arrays which do maintain order but this is broken as the size increases e.g.

```
(def m {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8 :i 9 :j 10 :k 11 :l 12 :m 13})
(into [] (select-keys m [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k]))
=> [[:e 5] [:k 11] [:g 7] [:c 3] [:j 10] [:h 8] [:b 2] [:d 4] [:f 6] [:i 9] [:a 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a reliable function to preserve orders, as well as `keys` and `vals` which do not preserve the order of how you defined the map.
The most reliable way is to use a `loop` / `recur` if you want to output an ordered vector of kv (or a `reduce` as well).
If you want ordered values only, you can use `juxt`.

I would add that pragmatically hashmaps are not meant to represent ordered data.

Comment: Yup, an associative unordered data structure is not aimed to collect ordered data, but Clojure still has `sorted-map` and `sorted-map-by` and that's what provoked me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering is a fairly simple one, you can easily sort the map by using `sorted-map-by`:

```
(def m (select-keys {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4} [:d :b]))
=> {:d 4, :b 2}

(def sm (sorted-map-by compare)) 
(into sm m)
=> {:b 2, :d 4}

(assoc *1 :c 1234)
=> {:b 2, :c 1234, :d 4}  ; maintains sort when additional kvs are assoc'd

(into [] *1)
=> [[:b 2] [:c 1234] [:d 4]]
```

Even if the ordering is not simple, you can write a custom comparator.  This is rife with pitfalls, but there is [a guide](http://clojure.org/guides/comparators) that is very good.  It's not what you were originally after, but it's relevant.

Comment: Note that `(sorted-map-by compare)` is equivalent to just `(sorted-map)`.